# What port is the Websphere app server's admin app on?

Tags: java, application-server, websphere

I've started Websphere on my local box and I can't remember what port the admin app should be on.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its usually 9060 for http and 9043 for https.

Comment: Be careful if you use RAD or RSA. Both install more than one server, so the ports may differ.

Answer (score 7):

There are several files (two of them look like reliable sources) in your WAS-profile that you can check (I used the paths from my installation, which uses mostly the standard settings):

1. {WAS-Profile-Path}\logs\AboutThisProfile.txt
2. {WAS-Profile-Path}\config\cells{cellname}\nodes{cellManagername}\serverindex.xml And look for WC_adminhost_secure or WC_adminhost.

The first one is easier since it is the smaller file. However, the second one is the actual configuration file. If you can't find the files. Search for a file that contains WC_adminhost or WC_adminhost_secure.

Comment: searching `serverindex.xml` for `WC_adminhost` showed the port I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `netstat` to get a list of the open ports; `netstat -ltnp` will give you listening ports with the process that has them open; it should be obvious where it is from there.